# Can't get all message using while loop

Tags: while-loop, at-command

I want to get all message from modem
one by one using while loop but its not working.
Whats wrong with my code.

```
def readInbox():
try:
    inboxempty = False
    while inboxempty == False:
        msg = WriteCMDwith_sleep("AT+CPMS?\r",2)
        smschk = CleanData(msg)
        smschk = smschk.split('SM', maxsplit=1)[-1]\
            .split(maxsplit=1)[0]
        if smschk > "0":
            balmsg = WriteCMDwith_sleep('AT+CMGL="ALL"\r',2)
            cleanRdata = CleanData(balmsg)
            parseAll = cleanRdata.split("+CMGL:")
            parsemsg = parseAll[1]
            smsIndex = parsemsg.partition(' ')[0]
            if (insert_message(parsemsg) == True):
                WriteCMDwith_sleep("AT+CMGD="+smsIndex+"\r",2)
        else:
            inboxempty = True
            break
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

Comment: What is the actual full response of `AT+CMGL="ALL"`? In other words: what is the value of `cleanRdata` before the parsing? (assuming that `CleanData()`, not included in your snippet actually reads the command response). Last but not least: are you sure that there are message in memory?

Comment: I already fixed, and the problem is this line "smsIndex = parsemsg.partition(' ')[0]" not working in my code. but i fixed changing partition to split

Comment: I'm happy you fixed it. Feel free to delete your question, as it actually cannot be answered